# How to do an automatic resize of a textbox as per data in the mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am fetching data from a mysql database and out of that fetched data, 4 fields are in the textbox.

So I want to resize the rows as per the total record present in the database.

I have used this code:

```
<tr bgcolor="#DFEFFF">

    <td align="left" style="vertical-align:top;">
         <h3>Description</h3>
    </td>

    <td align="left">
         <textarea name="feature" id="features" rows="5" cols="74" 

         disabled style="background-color:#DFEFFF; border:none; color:#000; font-

          family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px;">

         <?php echo $results['des']; ?>
         </textarea>
    </td>    
 </tr>
```

If I am using auto in rows = "auto", then even its not working.

Please help me to auto display in the textarea.

I want to, in case the admin uses copy paste method to insert the data, instead at the front end, the textarea will auto resize and contain all the data present in the database.

I am still looking for this answer. Please reply ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
#rtextarea { resize:vertical; max-height:300px; min-height:200px; }
#rtextarea.horiz { resize:horizontal; max-width:400px; min-width:200px; }
#rtextarea { resize:both; }
```